# Why does string.Format compile successfully if you don't specify all the arguments?

Tags: c#, .net

The following will throw an exception at runtime:

```
 string s = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",1,2,3,4);
```

but it will build successfully. Why?

Comment: Exceptions only occur at runtime, unless your compiler is broken.

Comment: @Matthew - I know exceptions occur at runtime. I am not asking why it doesn't throw an exception during the build, I am asking why does it build in the first place.

Comment: Why would it not build? That is fine in terms of syntax. Note that tools tile resharper will spot this for you

Comment: @MitchWheat - Answer accept, but not yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Format` for more than 3 parameters uses [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax so all parameters are passed like array, there is no runtime check if number of items corresponds to the format:

```
public static string Format(string format, object arg0);
public static string Format(string format, object arg0, object arg1);
public static string Format(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2);
public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

Comment: There will be no error for one or two parameters either. Compiler does not look inside the pattern string.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, where the format string is not necessarily a string literal, the compiler cannot possibly know whether sufficient arguments have been supplied.

In this specific case, the compiler could know, but the cost of describing in exactly which situations it should be treated as a compile-time error is rather high and risks fragmentation of C#, where some C# code compiles with one compiler and fails with another. There are at least three different C# compilers that get real world use, and they are supposed to follow the same spec. Treating this as a runtime error even in those cases where the problem is known at compile time is probably the least bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

Because `string.Format()` takes a variable argument list for more than 3 parameters (`params` syntax), and the compiler does not 'look inside' the format specifier string.

If you have Resharper installed, it will flag these as errors,

Comment: @xaisoft only with additional tools; from the compiler's perspective there is nothing special about string.format and it has no reason to attempt to parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler's job here is to resolve an appropriate string.Format method that matches the supplied arguments, taking I to account the applicable method group, signatures, conversion operators, etc - and generate the appropriate IL to make that happen. The compiler **does not care** what is in the string. The language specification does not mention `string.Format`, or any `{n}` etc rules that happen to go with it. To the compiler, it is just data to feed to `ldstr`.

There are tools that *will* spot this (resharper, for example), but: the compiler isn't in the least bit interested about what is inside this string.